# How can I add one class to the div tag and another class to the ul tag with jquery in the same sentence?

Tags: jquery, html

I added just one...

```
$(this).replaceWith($('<div> <ul>' + this.innerHTML + '</ul></div>').addClass('card_tr'));
```

Here is the image I took for my text editor, I an new.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you code line works correctly... But the only missing thing is a class to add to the `ul`...

Why not add it when you specify what to `replaceWith()`?

```
$(this).replaceWith($('<div> <ul class="HELLO">' + this.innerHTML + '</ul></div>').addClass('card_tr'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) you'll get a different selector result set, so you can chain methods together to get the effect you want.

```
$("DIV").addClass("class-for-div")   //Will apply only to the DIV
        .children("UL")
        .addClass("class-for-ul");   //Will apply only to the UL children and not the DIV itself
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this approach.

```
// Create temp variable that consist of div tag that is having 'firstClass' class and  ul with a class classed 'secondClass', then add existing html inside the element into ul tag.
var tmp = $('<div>').addClass('firstClass').append($('<ul>').addClass('secondClass').html($(this).html()));

// Replace current html element with tmp variable above.
$(this).html(tmp);
```